# String-from-decimal error

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, vb.net-2010

I have a textbox whose value is 0.00, and then I got an error converting... But I 
have made an example with 0.00 not from a textbox and it's working.. How do I fix this problem?

```
    Dim _Total, _Deduct, _Charges As String
    Dim _sss, _tax, _pf, _ph, _loan, _others, _hdmf, _cola, _allowance As Decimal
```

This line if textbox and comment this line is working.. but I use this not working..

```
    _sss = txtSSS.Text : _ph = txtPH.Text : _tax = txtInTax.Text : _pf = txtPF.Text
    _loan = txtLoan.Text : _hdmf = txtHDMF.Text : _others = txtOther.Text
    _cola = txtCola.ToString : _allowance = txtAllowance.ToString
```

This line is my given example value... The same value but the textbox is not working.. and this is working

```
    'This code when I uncomment.. this work..
    '_sss = "0.00": _ph = "0.00" : _tax = "0.00" : _pf = "0.00"
    '_loan = "0.00" : _hdmf = "50.00" : _others = "0.00"
    '_cola = "0.00" : _allowance = "0.00"

    _Charges = CDec(_cola) + CDec(_allowance)
    _Deduct = CDec(_sss) + CDec(_tax) + CDec(_pf) + CDec(_ph) + CDec(_loan) + CDec(_hdmf) + CDec(_others)

    _Total = CDec(_Charges) - CDec(_Deduct)

    lblDeduct.Text = Format((_Deduct), "currency")
    lblTotal.Text = FormatCurrency((_Total), 2, TriState.True, TriState.False, TriState.True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Decimal.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9zbda557.aspx):

```
<!-- language : lang-vb -->
If Not Decimal.TryParse(txtSSS.Text, _sss) Then
    ' do something if the value doesn't convert
End If
```

---

Based on your comment and playing with your code, see if this works for you (I used 0 for a default). If you don't have [`Option Strict`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/zcd4xwzs%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) turned on, do yourself a favor and do so.

From above `Option Strict` link:

> Restricts implicit data type conversions to only widening conversions, disallows late binding, and disallows implicit typing that results in an Object type.

```
Private Sub CalculateCurrency()
    If Not Decimal.TryParse(txtSSS.Text, _sss) Then _sss = 0D
    If Not Decimal.TryParse(txtPH.Text, _ph) Then _ph = 0D
    If Not Decimal.TryParse(txtInTax.Text, _tax) Then _tax = 0D
    If Not Decimal.TryParse(txtPF.Text, _pf) Then _pf = 0D
    If Not Decimal.TryParse(txtLoan.Text, _loan) Then _loan = 0D
    If Not Decimal.TryParse(txtHDMF.Text, _hdmf) Then _hdmf = 0D
    If Not Decimal.TryParse(txtOther.Text, _others) Then _others = 0D
    If Not Decimal.TryParse(txtCola.Text, _cola) Then _cola = 0D
    If Not Decimal.TryParse(txtAllowance.Text, _allowance) Then _allowance = 0D

    _Charges = CStr(_cola + _allowance)

    _Deduct = CStr(_sss + _tax + _pf + _ph + _loan + _hdmf + _others)

    _Total = CStr(CDec(_Charges) - CDec(_Deduct))

    lblDeduct.Text = Format((_Deduct), "currency")
    lblTotal.Text = FormatCurrency((_Total), 2, TriState.True, TriState.False, TriState.True)
End Sub
```

Comment: hmm.. sir.. what if is the value of the textbox is dynamic and can change by textchange.. i really dnt have a good idea how to work that.. TY for the reply..

Comment: @DeorwinBensurto put it in the TextBox's TextChanged Event

Comment: still dont know the good way to fix this sir.. i actually use the calculation for currency value.. but still not fix..